# Prolog - return list of unique numbers in nested lists

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

Hi everyone I'm trying to learn Prolog on my own and I am stuck trying to create a function that takes a nested list and returns a list of only the unique numbers. So unique(L,T) means that T is a list of unique numbers extracted from L.

The format of the lists look like this where c is always followed by an int:

`[a,[b,[c,5],[c,3]],[c,4]]`

Example of what should return as true:

```
unique([b,[c,4],[c,3]], [4,3])
```

This is the code I have tried however it is just returning an empty list when i try to query it:

```
unique([],[]).
unique([X|XS],[X|L]) :-
 integer(X),
 unique(XS,L).
unique([X|XS],L) :-
 \+integer(X),
 unique(XS,L).
```

I have tried various other solutions as well and seem to keep getting an empty list as output or just 'false'. I would appreciate any sort of guidance on this!

Answer (score 1):

This code does not take into account that the lists are nested; it should succeed on (for example):

```
unique([b,c,4,c,3],[4,3]).
```

You'll need a case where the head of the list is a list, recursively find the integers in that, and append what you find to what you find for the tail of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the list, filter it to get the numbers, sort to make them unique:

```
?- L = [a,[b,[c,5],[c,3]],[c,4]], flatten(L, F), include(number, F, N), sort(N, Unique_numbers).
L = [a, [b, [c, 5], [c, 3]], [c, 4]],
F = [a, b, c, 5, c, 3, c, 4],
N = [5, 3, 4],
Unique_numbers = [3, 4, 5].
```

If you want to keep the original order you can't sort, but there are many answers on SO that show you how to do it.

If you don't want to use the library predicates, look up how they are defined (`flatten/2` and `include/2`) and get inspiration for your own solution.